# Open a port to send over a variable in command-line Terminal not working

Tags: macos, command-line, terminal

Firstly, one Mac has terminal open to a random port:

```
nc -n -v -kl ****
```

I have a bash script in a command file on the other Mac:

```
message=$(osascript -e 'tell app "System Events" to text returned of (display dialog "random text" default answer "")')

nc -n -v (ip) **** < <(echo $message)
```

However, the code does not seem to work. How can I fix this?

Comment: What do you mean "does not seem to work"? The client has to know the random port that the host is opening in order to connect.

Comment: The client has the port open already, so they are waiting for the other person to run the bash script. I get an error and nothing goes through.

Comment: What is the error? The code worked fine for me.

Comment: It says "  syntax error near unexpected token `<'  "

Comment: Try double-quoting the `$message` variable (eg. `nc -n -v 123.123.123.123 1234 < <(echo "$message")`). You could also do `nc -n -v 123.123.123.123 1234 <<< "$message"`

Comment: The second worked for me! Thanks!